# Using window.open() to download file, how to not remove the # in URL?

Tags: javascript

So I am using JavaScript to download a file when an element is clicked like so:

HTML

```
<p onclick="download()">Click Here</p>
```

JavaScript

```
function download(){
    window.open("file.pdf")
}
```

Before the element is clicked, there is some #text in the URL like so: `folder/subfolder/index.html#text`

If the file opens up in the browser it replaces the current tab and when you press the back button to return to the page (such as with PDF), any #text **stays** in the URL. However, if the file is simply downloaded any #text gets **removed**.

How can I make it so #text is not removed or how could I return it to the URL? Since the page doesn't actually reload I am unable to put code in that might detect what #text should be in the URL. What could be another workaround?

The issue I am having is that one link downloads a file that doesn't open in the browser (not a PDF) so it causes the #text to disappear. Then, when I click on another link that does open a file in the browser (a PDF) when I click the back button, the #text is gone, but it is what allows my program to know what view to be on.

Answer (score 12):

Use `window.open("file.pdf", "_blank")`. This will open up a new tab temporarily to download the file then close it leaving the original page and URL in tact.

Comment: That's pretty much what it currently does, can see the tabs open very briefly as it prepares the download and when the file doesn't exist, the tab stays to say so. Adding "_blank" does seem to change how it functions.

Comment: I think it depends on the browser. For instance, I've noticed that with Chrome, opening a `.pdf` in a new tab does not start the download (a click by the user is required). Whereas, a `.zip` or `.tar.gz` will start downloading automatically.

Comment: It only opens a new tab for .pdf file.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<h1 onclick="Delete(event)">Fahith</h1>
<h1 onclick="Delete(event)">One</h1>
<h1 onclick="Delete(event)">Two</h1>
<h1 onclick="Delete(event)">Three</h1>
<h1 onclick="Delete(event)">Four</h1>
<h1 onclick="Delete(event)">Five</h1>
<h1 onclick="Delete(event)">Six</h1>
<h1 onclick="Delete(event)">Seven</h1>
<h1 onclick="Delete(event)">Eight</h1>

<script>
    function Delete(event){
        event.target.remove()
    }
</script>
```