# Download a file stored in firebase database from a javascript table

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am currently building a web application, i am quite new to javascript and i cant find a solution for something on my own. I am currently dragging some data from firebase database and display them in my website. My database looks like this

[image]

I am using html and javascript to create a table with the information from the firebase database and display it in my website. The html is code is the following:

```
<h3>Files List</h3>

                    <table class="zui-table zui-table-rounded" id="tbl_users_list" border="1">
                    <thead>
                    <tr>
                    <td>#ID</td>
                    <td>NAME</td>
                    <td>DATE</td>
                    <td>LINK</td>
                    </tr>
                     </thead>
                    </table>
                  </div>
```

In my javascript table i add another column with the name LINK. In this column I have some javascript buttons. What I am trying to do is to give the url of each file stored in my firebase database as a value to the corresponding button, so when the user clicks on the button of the corresponding file to be able to download it in his pc but I can't find a solution to this can someone please help me?

My javascript source code is the following:

```
var tblUsers = document.getElementById('tbl_users_list');
var databaseRef = firebase.database().ref('files/');
var rowIndex = 1;

databaseRef.once('value',function(snapshot){
snapshot.forEach(function(childsnapshot) { 
var childKey = childsnapshot.key;
var childData = childsnapshot.val();

var row = tblUsers.insertRow(rowIndex);
var cellId = row.insertCell(0);
var cellName = row.insertCell(1);
var cellName2 = row.insertCell(2);
var button = row.insertCell(3);

var itd = document.createElement('input');
itd.setAttribute("type","button");
itd.setAttribute("value","Download");

cellId.appendChild(document.createTextNode(childKey));
cellName.appendChild(document.createTextNode(childData.name));
cellName2.appendChild(document.createTextNode(childData.created));
button.appendChild(itd);

rowIndex = rowIndex+1;
```

My table looks like this

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to retrieve the url:

```
var childKey = childsnapshot.key;
var childData = childsnapshot.val();
var urls=childData.url;
```

then onclick of the button download the file.

```
var itd = document.createElement('input');
itd.onclick=function () {
window.open(childData.url);
};
```

`window.open()` will download the file according to this:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open

[Using window.open() to download file, how to not remove the # in URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31923255/using-window-open-to-download-file-how-to-not-remove-the-in-url)

Answer (score 1):

If you use links instead, you could use the [HTML5 download](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_download.asp) attribute:

```html
<a href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/uIhLA.jpg?s=32&g=1" download>Click to download Peter Haddad's profile pic</a>
```

You could also set the name of the file, but by setting the value of the attribute as long as it's an internal image. (E.g. dowload="name-of-file")